# Wait for animations on child elements to complete before moving to new route

Tags: angular

I have a route which contains elements that have `:enter` and `:leave` animations.
Little things like changing colours, fade-in, etc.

When the page loads the `:enter` animations fire just fine, however when leaving the page, the route changes and doesn't wait for the `:leave` animations to fire before completing the route change.

Is there a way to pause the route change to wait for the animations to complete?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  styles:[`div {background-color: blue;}`],
  template: `
  <div class="row " [@routerTransition]>
    <h2>Component</h2> 
  </div>
  `,
    animations: [trigger('routerTransition', [
      state('void', style({opacity: 1, height: 0}) ),
      state('*', style({opacity: 1}) ),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({opacity: 0}),
        animate('1s ease-in-out', style({opacity: 1}))
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        style({opacity: 1}),
        animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({opacity: 0}))
      ])
   ])]
})
export class YourComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```